# How to pass passphrase on the ansible cli?

Tags: ansible

I am running the following command,

```
ansible --args="top -b n1" --connection=ssh --inventory-file=xx.xx.xxx.xxx, all --extra-vars="ansible_user=devuser" --private-key /opt/hivecenter/keys/id_rsa_135
Enter passphrase for key '/opt/hivecenter/keys/id_rsa_135':
```

As this key is passphrase protected it is prompting me to provide passphrase, but i want to provide passphrase in the command itself. how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a passphrase for your key? If your system is secure, a passphrase isn't really necessary. Besides, sending a passphrase in cleartext in your command is not recommended, because the command will be saved in your Command Line History when you run it.

[This answer might be your best choice](https://serverfault.com/a/758461)

Another option is to use Python with the Pexpect module to execute the command and automatically send the passphrase.

Comment: command line history will not be a problem as i will be masking all the secrets but is there any way to pass it in command line ?

Comment: Take a look at the "Securely storing key passphrases" section in [this webpage](https://blog.packetdisarray.com/2015/08/06/passphrase-ssh-keys-without-repetitive-typing/) . Here is [another webpage that explains the same](https://www.randomhacks.co.uk/how-to-ssh-key-with-a-passphrase-but-not-have-to-enter-it-all-the-time/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python (or don't mind to use it), you can use pexpect module to execute the Ansible command in the background and automatically pass the passphrase.

Comment: That is not feasible for me :( . So we cannot pass it in command line?